# Creating dictionary with binary search tree and hashing

Tags: java, hash, binary-search-tree

I’m about to create a "smart" dictionary that could generate similar words if the word from the user is not in the dictionary.

The dictionary starts with reading a file with words, the word should be added to the binary tree and a hash table. The hash table is used to determine if the word or similar word is in the dictionary, the hash Table will have a Boolean effect so we can fast look if the binary search tree contains the word. The hash Table has to be around ten times the length of our dictionary, because we also include similar words to the hash Table.
As relatively new to Java, I would like tips and suggestions for how to make a hash function that would be ideal for my situation.

```
public String [] similarOne(String word) {

    char [] word_array = word.toCharArray();
    char [] tmp;

    String [] words = new String[word_array.length-1];

    for(int i = 0; i < word_array.length - 1; i++) {
        tmp = word_array.clone();
        words[i] = swap(i, i+1, tmp);
    }
    return words;
}

public String swap(int a, int b, char [] word) {
    char tmp = word[a];
    word[a] = word[b];
    word[b] = tmp;

    return new String(word);
}
```

Comment: This is heavily dependent on whether you are trying to match words with common start or deal with misspellings, etc. To start with, exactly what do you mean by "work from the user is not in the dictionary"? Is the word misspelled? Is the word correctly spelled but pluralized? Do you mean mapping between US and British English?

Comment: What do you mean by a "similar word"? Do you mean a word that sounds similar? That has a similar definition? A key question here is whether similarity is transitive. That is, if A is similar to B and B is similar to C, does that mean that A must be similar to C? If so, then something that maps all similar words to a common token will work for you. If not, if, say, "quick" is similar to "fast" and "fast" is similar to "tight" but "quick" is not similar to "tight", then the data structure must be more complex.

Comment: What do you mean by "hash table will have a boolean effect so we can fast look in the binary search tree"? I'm not sure if you're thinking that a hash table uses a tree -- it doesn't -- or if you're intent is to have a hash table and a binary tree that are somehow related to each other.

Comment: This is a school assignment. The method over I used to generate similar words. The algorithm should work like this: When reading the file, insert word into the binary tree and hash table. When a user gives a String input (that should be a word the user want to look after) the word should be looked after in the hash table, if the word is in the hash table the algorithm should start to find the word in the binary tree. If the word wasn’t found in the binary tree or in the hasttable there should be generated similar words and test them same way, and then print out suggestions if anyone found.

Answer (score 0):

Google for 'java metaphone' and 'java soundex'.

You could try using the results of a [Metaphone](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html) encoding as the hash key, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use a [Trie](http://code.google.com/p/trie/) or [patricia-trie](http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/).I don't know what you mean by similar words.But i'm guessing it is something like google suggest.I have wrote a small [program](http://www.2shared.com/file/2EeoO5dA/wordCompletejar.html) previously which does auto-complete.It has a dependency with patricia-trie so will have to include it.You can use it as a reference.